# Parsing online images into ImageView

Tags: android, json, android-imageview

I am trying to parse online images into ImageView using JSON and for that i am using Picasso library

But i am not getting online image into ImageView due to big size of image, Width: 4608 pixels and Height: 2592 pixels

```
    Picasso.with(context)
    .load(imageURL)
    .noFade()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

**Note:-** I am getting small size image into ImageView successfully

Comment: You need to scale down your image

Comment: @Raghunandan how can i do that ?

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply custom transforms.

I used the below to scale the image keeping the aspect ratio

```
Transformation transformation = new Transformation() {
@Override 
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {

            int targetWidth = width;
            double aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
            int targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth  * aspectRatio);

            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);

            if (result != source) {
                // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
                source.recycle();
            }

            return result;

        }
```

Then

```
Picasso.with(context).
          load("your url").transform(transformation)
          .into(holder.iv)
```

Look at image transformations @

http://square.github.io/picasso/

for adding custom transforms based on your requirement

You can also have a look@

https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit/

Comment: i have tried your code, check here: http://paste.ofcode.org/nXW6SLQUufKjJD2iewhLXz but getting: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
  FieldDeclaration
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Comment: String imageURL = filesArrayList.get(position).getfilename();;  ? why double ;  and you havent used the transformation created in the picaso loader

Comment: @Sophie look at the braces closing and opening. I had the transformation in getView itself

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu oh sorry that was the typo mistake and i have used transformation in the picasso loader as well, check: http://paste.ofcode.org/rKpU9RndKuBRYdgfAYVjdr

Comment: @Raghunandan ok moved transformation code in getView() but still getting: width cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @Sophie i defined a width myself which was the width of the screen. You can scale and resize according to what width and height you want the image to be

Comment: @Raghunandan hi tried your code, noticed few things, first of all it's taking huge time to show image into imageview, second i have to scroll up and down to load images and not working perfect in portrait mode

Comment: @Sophie scaling if necessary. next profile your code to see if there is overdraw or if the frames are dropping. it should be under 16ms seconds. So if you see any glitch in scrolling you need to do all those things

Comment: @Sophie check this http://www.curious-creature.com/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html. If you can scale your image on the server that would be better

Comment: @Raghunandan have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646619/captured-image-resolution-is-too-big

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(imageURL)
    .noFade()
    .fit()
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

Comment: getting: Cannot invoke fit() on the primitive type void

Comment: .fit().centerCrop() will come before into() method